# When printing, Firefox cuts off/crops images if they're larger then a single print page, how do I disable this behavior?

Tags: html, css, image, printing

If I have an image on a webpage that exceedes the height of a single print page, the lower half of it gets cut off/cropped by Firefox when printed (e.g. viewed in Print Preview), this does not happen in Chrome and probably not IE either, not sure about Opera and others.

How can I disable this cuting off/cropping and get the full image on two or more pages?

I'd preferibly do it through HTML/CSS/Javascript rather then browser setting, but if it is a browser setting issue I guess I'll just have to trust my users to do it.

Comment: OK, I might know some CSS that can help, but I need to understand more. Can you explain exactly what you want in detail? Or maybe draw a diagram? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a print setting--the user needs to select "Shrink To Fit" or the like. I believe it is the default option anyway.

Comment: Wouldn't that just shrink the image into a single page? If it exceeds the height of a single page I need it to cross over to the second page, not shrink (or crop) to the first.

Comment: Oh, I see. I have no idea how to fix that, sorry. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
overflow: visible !important;
```