# Printing from knitr/rmarkdown crops images and introduces linebreaks

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am creating a questionnaire and want to let users to **save the results as `pdf`**.

The `html` looks fine! But `printing` crops the image and nothing has worked so far.

[image]

**Edit:** I add a fitting [quote](http://www.andreacirillo.com/2019/01/27/a-quick-ride-on-pagedown-create-pdf-from-rmarkdown/) about the pagedown package, probably describing the problem:

> "[...] try to generate PDF from one of your Rmarkdown files, and by a
> PDF I mean that kind of document where images are note broken into
> half from page to page and written text does not finish beyond the end
> of the page… (yeah, I know you know what I mean bu that…)"

```
# YAML
---
output: 
    pdf_document:   #html?
        fig_crop: false                         # doesn't work
---

---
output:
  pagedown::html_paged:                         # doesn't work
    css: ["default-fonts", "default-page", "default"]
---

# CSS line-breaks
<style media="print">
    html, body, p, hr, img { 
    break-after:  avoid !important;             # doesn't work
    break-before: avoid !important;             # doesn't work
    break-inside: always !important;            # doesn't work
    } 
</style>

# Button
<input type="button" value="Print this page" onClick="window.print()">
```

````
# Example Plot
     ```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
    library(ggplot2)
    Plot <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point()
    Plot + facet_grid(rows = vars(drv))
    plot.height <- 45
     ```


# Calling the plot (with fig.height)
    ```{r, fig.height=plot.height, strip.white = TRUE} # doesn't work
     plot(Plot)
    ```
````

Here is the example implemented:
https://exampleruntest.formr.org
For some reason the example plot does not introduce the line break before the plot, but afterwards.

I hope someone has an idea

Comment: Have you tried out the `pagedown` package?

Comment: No, but it looks promising! I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question:

1. The **image cropping turned out to be a firefox specific issue.**
   Solutions are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355951/when-printing-firefox-cuts-off-crops-images-if-theyre-larger-then-a-single-pri) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609007/firefox-printing-only-1st-page), while the latter worked for my case by adding `display:block;` to the CSS
2. Removing the **page-break after the header** by wrapping the image of the plot with a `<div>` (overriding the default `<p>`) using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15374583/11492942) solution.